# Sending attachment file via json

Tags: rest, web-services

I am new in REST so just wondering is it possible to send PDF document(attachment) via json through rest API. I know SOAP protocol supports attachment but does REST also support attachment.If yes then how we can send it through Json?

Comment: what framework are you using? Spring, Jersey ?

Comment: Jersey 1.8 version and JSF

Comment: why dont u use multipart upload. please refer https://howtodoinjava.com/jersey/jersey-file-upload-example/